# must declare the scalar variable @columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I've got error:

> Must declare the scalar variable @columns

Where is the problem? Thank you

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CreateTable
@tabname nvarchar(max)
as
declare @columns nvarchar(max) = null;
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = null;
select @columns=coalesce(@columns + ', ')
+colname
+ ' '
+coltype 
from x_column
where colname is not null
and tabname=@tabname
order by colnum;

set @sql =IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE 
object_id=OBJECT_ID(N'[@tabname]') AND type in (N'U'))
create table ' + @tabname + ' (' + @columns + ');
print @sql;
-- execute create table
exec sp_sqlexec @sql;
GO
```

Comment: So, you tried answers?

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CreateTable
    @tabname nvarchar(max)
as
    declare @columns nvarchar(max) = null;
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = null;

    SELECT @columns = STUFF((SELECT ',' + colname + ' ' + coltype
    FROM x_column
    WHERE colname IS NOT NULL
        AND tabname = @tabname
    ORDER BY colnum
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

    set @sql ='IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE 
    object_id=OBJECT_ID(N['+@tabname+']) AND type in (N''U''))
    create table [' + @tabname + '] (' + @columns + ');'

    print @sql;
    -- execute create table
    exec sp_sqlexec @sql;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CreateTable @tabname NVARCHAR(max)
AS
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(max) = NULL;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = NULL;

SELECT @columns = coalesce(@columns, ', ') + colname + ' ' + coltype
FROM x_column
WHERE colname IS NOT NULL
    AND tabname = @tabname
ORDER BY colnum;

SET @sql = 'IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE 
object_id=OBJECT_ID(N[' + @tabname + ']) AND type in (N''U''))
create table [' + @tabname + '] (' + @columns + ');'

PRINT @sql;

-- execute create table
EXEC sp_sqlexec @sql;
GO
```

Comment: Check your coalesce function part. I can't understand what you are doing there

Comment: I need to find colname and coltype in x_colum(table) with select columns. Then in set sql I want to create table with those colums.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error with `coalesce` and for `@sql` the data is not loaded properly

So the below script will work:

```
alter PROCEDURE CreateTable
    @tabname nvarchar(max)
as

declare @columns nvarchar(max) = null;
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = null;

select @columns = coalesce(@columns , ', ') + colname + ' ' + coltype 
from x_column
where colname is not null
and tabname = @tabname
order by colnum;

set @sql = 'IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE 
                           object_id = OBJECT_ID(N[' + @tabname + ']) AND type in (N''U'')) 

create table ' + @tabname + ' (' + @columns + ');'
print @sql;
-- execute create table
exec sp_sqlexec @sql;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
set @sql ='IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE 
object_id=OBJECT_ID('+@tabname+') AND type in (''U''))
create table ' + @tabname + ' (' + @columns + ')';`
```